# How to cut a piece of a drawing and then making a new layer, paste that piece into it

Tags: layers, krita

Let's say I have a flower. I want to cut one petal, make a new layer, and then paste that part in there, without that petal looking choppy or anything.

How would I do this?

Thank you!

***Note:*** *I am using Krita.*

Comment: Select the petal using one of the selection tools in Krita, then copy and paste it.  You don't have to make a new layer first. Krita pastes as a new layer by default.

Comment: I'll try this out. Thank you!